# Migrating from old Dropbox SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-sdk

I'm migrating from the old Dropbox Obj-C SDK to the new one. I was using the following methods from the old SDK:

`- deletePath:
- uploadFile:toPath:withParentRev:fromPath:
- loadMetadata:
- cancelAllRequests`

And a bunch of delegate calls:

`- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client
      uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath
          metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client deletedPath:(NSString *)path
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client deletePathFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client metadataUnchangedAtPath:(NSString*)path
- (void)restClient:(DBUserClient*)client loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
- (void)sessionDidReceiveAuthorizationFailure:(DBSession*)session userId:(NSString *)userId`

The new SDK doesn't seem to have anything like these methods - or delegates. I'm somewhat surprised that an SDK would be updated to be so completely different than what was already there. I am thinking that maybe I've got something wrong, that maybe there's another SDK I am missing? Surely it can't be that hard, despite any API changes, to maintain an SDK in a way that transitioning would be simple and intuitive, and not requiring major changes to the client code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/DBRestClient-and-DBRestClientDelegate-replacement-in-v2/m-p/279439#M16767 ]

The Dropbox API v2 Objective-C SDK isn't built from the old Dropbox Core API v1 Objective-C SDK, so performing these actions works differently:

> - deletePath:

Use [`deleteV2`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESUserAuthRoutes(im)deleteV2:).

> - uploadFile:toPath:withParentRev:fromPath:

Use one of [the upload methods](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESUserAuthRoutes(im)uploadUrl:inputUrl:). There's [an example here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#upload-style-request).

> - loadMetadata:

To get the metadata for a specific file, use [`getMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESUserAuthRoutes(im)getMetadata:). To list the contents of a folder, use [`listFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESUserAuthRoutes(im)listFolder:) and [`listFolderContinue`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/api-docs/latest/Classes/DBFILESUserAuthRoutes.html#/c:objc(cs)DBFILESUserAuthRoutes(im)listFolderContinue:).

> - cancelAllRequests

The Dropbox API v2 Objective-C SDK doesn't offer a helper method like this for cancelling all requests at once. (We'll consider it a feature request though.) Instead, the methods return task objects you can track. You can then cancel any/all of the tasks as desired. For any particular task, that would look like:

```
DBUploadTask *req = [client.filesRoutes upload...
[req cancel];
```